# Odd request. iMac physical machine, want to bootcamp to windows native, then run mac os X in VM

Tags: windows, mac, virtual-machines

I think the subject says it all, but I couldn't find any info quite fitting my desire anywhere.  It's hard to search for this and not get tons of articles involving hackintoshes or running a VM on mac.

I want to boot natively into Windows XP (that's working just great).

Currently, I can boot into Mac, too, and run XP in a VM, but I really don't want to do it that way as I spend most of my time in Windows.

So, is there a way to, on the Windows side, buy another version of VMWare fusion (or whatever I need), create a new vhd, install mac osx on it, and make my life about 10x easier than it currently is?

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this can work, quite easily actually - the only problem is that there's no legal way of getting an OSX VM image. But it does work, I'm doing it right now using VMWare Workstation 6.5.

Comment: Legality concerns me.  But thanks for letting me know that it is possible.  I might go read over my license agreement for the developer's preview copy of snow leopard that I got from WWDC...maybe I can find a hole in that...

Comment: The other thing to take into account Matt is that your VM may not just boot up off the OSX install DVD - even if it does it may not work. I got mine via a torrent and it was already installed and setup - that was very naughty but I thought you should know.

Comment: :)  very naughty indeed.  Hey, I'm not judging.  Development is difficult and sometimes the license agreements make things difficult, if not impossible.

Answer (score 2):

According to the current licensing, you'll need OS X server. That's the only legal way to virtualize OS X at the moment:

http://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2008/06/virtual-leopard.html

Specifically, it requires that it be run on Apple hardware, which almost coincidentally, you are. Bonus.

Comment: Excellent!  Not sure how much OSX Server is, but at least it is an option.  Thanks.

Comment: The current shipping version is $499 USD for the 10-client version, $999 USD for an unlimited client, the Snow Leopard version coming in September is $499 for unlimited clients.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be looking at [VMware Workstation](http://vmware.com/products/ws/) since you are running from the Windows side - although I have to ask why you would want to do this.

OS X is a 64bit operating system allowing access to more RAM, has fewer viruses to contend with and in general, makes a much better (personal unfounded opinion) host system than the other way around. Perhaps using [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) would get you the XP access you need while leveraging OS X.

Comment: The only reason why I want to do this is that I'm in windows 95% of the time, and my compile needs on windows are on much larger projects than the compile needs I have on Mac, since on Mac I'm doing iPhone apps which are very very small.  It just makes more sense for my particular, highly specialized, situation than most people's situations.

Comment: @Matt - I understand you want Windows easily accessible - hence the parallels environment which essentially lets you run Windows apps on your OS X install. It's not as fast as running directly via bootcamp but the difference is minimal.

Comment: I run VMWare, and I have noticed a difference.  It's not terrible, but it isn't none.  I'm specifically talking about straight compile times to build an asp.net site.  Also, for 1 project, I have to connect to their network (a bank) via VPN, and the connection drops quite often when I'm running windows under mac, but hardly ever if I'm running straight in windows from bootcamp.  Again, that is purely anecdotal, but they are my anecdotes so they 100% true for my situation.  Thanks for the response, though.